# How to interact multiple chaincode in go lang for hyperledger fabric

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode, chaincode

How to interact multiple chaincode in go lang for hyperledger fabric
how to call one function into another chaincode in hyperledger fabric

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using [fabric-contract-api-go](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-contract-api-go) for your smart contract implementation:

1. Get the chaincode stub from the transaction context with [GetStub()](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-contract-api-go@v1.2.0/contractapi#TransactionContextInterface)
2. Use the stub to invoke the second chaincode with [InvokeChaincode()](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-go/shim#ChaincodeStubInterface)

If you are using the low-level [fabric-chaincode-go](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-go) for your chaincode implementation then your transactions are invoked with the chaincode stub rather than a transaction context, so you can ignore step one and just call [InvokeChaincode()](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-go@v0.0.0-20220920210243-7bc6fa0dd58b/shim#ChaincodeStub.InvokeChaincode) on the stub.